# Is the series converges?$\sum \frac{1}{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)^p},\quad \quad p\in\mathbb R$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series convergent?If so, for what values of $p$?
$$\sum \frac{1}{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)^p},\quad \quad p\in\mathbb R$$

Comment: Are you trying to show convergence for all $p$? If so, this series will not converge.

Comment: no... for what values of p it will converge

Comment: You should edit your post to include that information

Comment: no.. for what values it will converges?

Comment: Though the posted answers are fine, another way of seeing this is using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Answer (score 3):

For a large value of $n$ we have

$$n\ge \log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)^p$$
so
$$\frac1{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)^p}\ge\frac1n$$
and the series $\sum\frac1n $ is divergent so the given series is divergent by comparison.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)^p}=\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{p\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)}=\dfrac{1}{p}\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)}$

$\dfrac{1}{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)}>\dfrac{1}{n}$

$\therefore\displaystyle\sum \frac{1}{\log\left(\left(\log\left(\log\left(\log n\right)\right)\right)\right)^p}$ diverges for all $p\in \mathbb {R}$

Comment: I interpreted the expression as $(\log(u))^p$ and not $\log(u^p)$, although I guess it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

For general $p$ note that the successive logs do not matter as for each $n$ there is a $k$ such that $log(log(...log(k)) > log(n)$. Using the well-ordering principle take the least such $k$ ($\lceil e^{e^{e^k}} \rceil$) for each $n$ to reduce to the case $log(n)^p$.

Then look at $1/log(n)^p$ vs $1/n$.

For each $n$ there is a $p$ such that $1/log(n)^p > 1/n$; namely $p < log(n)/log(log(n))$. This number is increasing and unbounded... That is sort of a weird way to see that this will not converge.

The correct way is to (for fixed $p$) bound $lg(n)^p - n < 0$; this is $n e^{-n^{1/p}} < 1$. So you need $n$ so that $n/e^{n^{1/p}} < 1$. I think you can find this... Hint break it into 2 cases. Note that for the cases $p < 1$ the denominator is less that $log(n)$ which does not converge (as each term is greater than $1/n$ which does not converge). For $p > 1$ $n > lg(n)$ asymptotically is all you need.